# Making an SQL query perform better with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that currently takes 4 minutes to run. I'm trying to get it down to about 2 minutes. The query basically looks into a table that is about 25,000 rows. It grabs each item and tries to find a match to a table with about 230 rows.

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Iterator INT
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @tempView TABLE (viewID int identity, 
                      intCarrierCode int,
                      chrDlrNum varchar(50),
                      chrPgmCode varchar(5),
                      chrCvgCode varchar(5),
                      chrTransType varchar(5),
                      chrFeeType varchar(5),
                      chrPayeeType varchar(5),
                      intPayeeCode int,
                      Count int,
                      Amount smallmoney);
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (tableID int identity,
                      inbAcctgID int,
                      chrCarrierDesc varchar(50),
                      chrCarrierDescSht varchar(50),
                      intAcctCustID int,
                      intAcctCo int,
                      intAcctCoRec int,
                      chrPgmCode varchar(5), 
                      intCarrierCode int,
                      chrDlrNum varchar(50),
                      chrCvgCode varchar(5),
                      chrPayeeType varchar(5),
                      chrFeeType varchar(5),
                      intPayeeCode int,
                      chrTransType varchar(5),
                      Count int,
                      Amount smallmoney)

Truncate Table tblPayeeTransactionsMatchMonthEnd

INSERT into @tempView     (intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrPgmCode,chrCvgCode,chrTransType,chrFeeType,chrPayeeType,intPay eeCode,Count,Amount)
SELECT * FROM dbo.viewMonthendArchiveGroupByCovg Where chrPgmCode <> 'BIW' and   chrPayeeType <> 'M' and chrTransType Not in ('CXS','VOD','SUS','DEN') and Amount <> 0


SET @Iterator = 1
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempView)

WHILE (@Iterator <= @RowCount)
BEGIN

IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
        and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
        and (A.chrDlrNum = V.chrDlrNum OR A.chrDlrNum is NULL)
        and (A.chrTransType = V.chrTransType OR A.chrTransType IS NULL)
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
            and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
            and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
            and (A.chrDlrNum = V.chrDlrNum OR A.chrDlrNum is NULL)
            and (A.chrTransType = V.chrTransType OR A.chrTransType IS NULL)
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
        and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
        and (A.chrDlrNum = V.chrDlrNum OR A.chrDlrNum is NULL)
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
            and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
            and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
            and (A.chrDlrNum = V.chrDlrNum OR A.chrDlrNum is NULL)
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
        and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
            and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode OR A.intPayeeCode is NULL)
            and (A.chrCvgCode = V.chrCvgCode OR A.chrCvgCode is NULL)
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        and A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
            and (A.intPayeeCode = V.intPayeeCode)
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        and A.intPayeeCode is NULL
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
            and A.intPayeeCode is NULL
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
            and A.chrFeeType = V.chrFeeType
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
            and A.chrPayeeType = V.chrPayeeType
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
            and A.intCarrierCode = V.intCarrierCode
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
        (SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,V.chrPgmCode,V.intCarrierCode, V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        FROM @tempView as V
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END

Set @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
END 

Begin

Insert into    tblPayeeTransactionsMatchMonthEnd(inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
Select inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount from @tempTable

End`
```

Sorry about the length. Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried going from Select Count(*) to Count just one column, but it made zero difference.

Comment: It's seems to me that every condition, other then the `ELSE` insert the exact same data `Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount` into @tempTable I'm missing something?

Comment: That is not a query - that is procedural code in a set based environment. As in: SLOW. Make it set based and be happy with that. Check execution plans and add all relevant needed indices. Finished. And no need for a temporary table.

Comment: what do you mean by "make it set based"?

Comment: Serpiton - yes it inserts the same columns, but its a different row every time based on the match

Comment: What he means by set-based is that you should be able to reduce almost all of that into a single statement, and doing the mental work to make that possible will likely get this to run in less than a second; forget 2 minutes.

Comment: can you give a small example of how it could be reduced?

Answer (score 1):

It is realy hard to say what is exactly wrong, but firstly you should check indexes on the fields in your tables that you use in `where` clause and after `ON` in inner join.
Also I see such syntax like:

```
if(select count(1) from t where something= something) = 1
begin
   insert into A from t where something= something
end
```

This is bad practice. Use just like this:

```
begin tran
       insert into A from t where something= something
if @@rowcount > 1 -- this is you requirement that needs just one row needs instead of if(select count(1) from t where something= something) = 1
  rollback tran
else
  commit tran
```

In  this case you will have only one `select` instead of two. There are a lot of such cases and I thing you will get greate performance if change it carefully

In addition, you can include client statistics (I/O and time)

```
set statistics time on
go
set statistics io on
go
```

and you will see what is part of query work slow exactly.

Comment: This way has taken longer so far

Comment: Do you really check that indexes are exist? Can you show part of client statistic?

Answer (score 0):

The all `IF` structure is equivalent to

```
IF (Select COUNT(intActgAcctID) 
From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
    ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
    where V.viewID = @Iterator) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
       (Select A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        From dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A INNER JOIN @tempView as V
        ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
        (SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,V.chrPgmCode,V.intCarrierCode, V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
        FROM @tempView as V
        where V.viewID = @Iterator)
END
```

there is no need to check column per column if the check on `chrPgmCode` is enought to pass the data to `@tempTable`

That mean that if `tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2` and `tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts`
have the same data this is equivalent to

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
SELECT A.inbAcctgID,A.chrCarrierDesc,A.chrCarrierDescSht,A.intAcctCustID,A.intAcctCo,A.intAcctCoRec,A.chrPgmCode,A.intCarrierCode,V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
FROM dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A 
     INNER JOIN @tempView as V ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode

INSERT INTO @tempTable (inbAcctgID,chrCarrierDesc,chrCarrierDescSht,intAcctCustID,intAcctCo,intAcctCoRec,chrPgmCode,intCarrierCode,chrDlrNum,chrCvgCode,chrPayeeType,chrFeeType,intPayeeCode,chrTransType,Count,Amount)
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,V.chrPgmCode,V.intCarrierCode, V.chrDlrNum,V.chrCvgCode,V.chrPayeeType,V.chrFeeType,V.intPayeeCode,V.chrTransType,V.Count,V.Amount
FROM   @tempView as V
where  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   dbo.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts as A 
                          INNER JOIN @tempView as V ON A.chrPgmCode = V.chrPgmCode
                  )
```

without any cursor or iterator

Comment: being equal on JUST chrPgmCode ISNT enough to pass it to temp table, its a last resort

Comment: I ran just that and it took about a minute and returned the table i had in the first place

Comment: @Zingo Without test data it's difficult to say why, for what I can know all the rows in `tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts` match with one in filtered viewMonthendArchiveGroupByCovg, if you can create a SQLFiddle with data that match and don't match I'll check it